# How's TCP connection established with reverse proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, tcp, proxy

I've setup Nginx server to act as a reverse proxy for Apache. Now I'm wondering how TCP connections are established and closed in this workflow. My assumption is that the first TCP connection is established between a browser and Nginx, then Nginx establishes second TCP connection to the Apache. When response from Apache is returned, Nginx closes this connection and returns response to the browser. Is this how it's actually done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Nginx creates 2 connections for 1 request from a client: Client <---> Nginx <---> Apache.

For better performance you should configure buffering (as example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching)

And look on proxy_redirect directive.

Comment: thanks, do you have experience with sockets reverse proxy?

Comment: Do you mean web sockets or unix sockets?
For unix-sockets I don't think you need to use proxy_redirect.

Comment: web sockets reverse proxy configuration

Comment: to proxy websocket HTTP connection to backend should keep alive (header Connection value should not be "close" at least)

Answer (score 0):

Nginx creates two connections, that's correct. except that it does not close the connection, but keeps it open so that it can use it for other requests as well.